# Unknown getSystemService()

Tags: java, android

So I'm following along with [this tutorial](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/), and I'm stuck. In Eclipse, I'm getting an error saying that "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type UserItemAdapter".  Any idea how I can get this from a Context? I'm kinda confused, I haven't done much with with Contexts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your enclosing Activity is `MyActivity`, use `MyActivity.this.getSystemService()`. This will access the enclosing Activity (which is a Context).

EDIT: or `getContext().getSystemService` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getContext%28%29)

Comment: Sweet, I used `getContext().getSystemService`. Thanks a bunch :D